# Setting a transform-origin of a CSS3 pseudo 3d object

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to build a "pseudo 3D" CSS3 slideshow to hold the projects for my website.

The code I have for each element is

```
<div class="projects">                  
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section id="widget_sp_image-8" class="widget widget_sp_image">
       <h1 class="widget-title">Live Manager</h1>
       <div class="widget_sp_image-description">
       <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
       </div>
     </section>
     <!-- And so on -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Basically, all each card is set to position: absolute; and I rotate them around 360 degrees width Javascript. I want to rotate it around it itself by 45deg every time an user presses  left or right, but I have difficulties setting it's transform origin. I have this as a code:

```
.projects .wrapper {
    width: 470px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-700px);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
}
```

But when the left or right arrows are pressed, the slideshow start rotating awkwardly around its side, so the transform-origin doesn't do the trick.

Here is a link to the codepen project: 
http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/qyfzp

Answer (score 0):

2 problem!
first when you translate your wrapper -720px in Z axis, so must translate your origin -720px in Z axis too!

```
.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -700px;
}
```

and second problem is:
`wrapper.style.webkitTransform +=` is wrong! because in every key pressing its value will be duplicated!
currently i fix it, but it's not a good way to rotate it!

see [[ THIS ]](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AcaoJ)

Comment: Thanks man, much appreciated! I didn't know you can use the Z axis in transform origin...